# Powershell variable - verbose if it is receiving input

Tags: powershell, variables, zip, 7zip, verbose

I have created a script that compress files older than N days using PowerShell.
Like this:

```
param (
    $dirPath, `
    [int] $daysAgo, `
    $logOutput=$dirPath+"\old_reports.log", `
    $fileExt
    )

$curDate = Get-Date
$timeAgo = ($curDate).AddDays($daysAgo)

$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse `
                       -Path $dirPath `
                       -Include *.$fileExt| `
                       Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $timeAgo } | `
                       Select -ExpandProperty FullName

& 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7Z.exe' a -t7z -mx9 old_reports.7z $files -bb1 -sdel

echo $files > $logOutput
```

It is working, but, since there are many files, it takes a while to fill the `$files` variable. While it is doing that, the prompt shows only a blinking cursor. Therefore, I am not aware if the script is actually doing something or it's paused by an accidental click.

Is there a way to show that `$files` variable is receiving input?

Comment: Could you expand that `Where-Object` into a ForEach and write output when it finds a qualifying file? If the longest leg is the `Get-ChildItem` and not `Where-Object` you could take off the recurse and do that manually. Another option would be to start it as a background job with Start-Job and monitor the progress and output every so often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without restructuring your command - and thereby sacrificing performance - I see only one option:

In addition to capturing file-info objects in variable `$files`, print them to the display as well, which you can do with the help of the [common `-OutVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-outvariable):

```
# Output the files of interest *and* capture them in 
# variable $files, via -OutVariable
Get-ChildItem -Recurse `
                       -Path $dirPath `
                       -Include *.$fileExt| `
                       Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $timeAgo } | `
                       Select -ExpandProperty FullName -OutVariable files
```

Comment: That worked great. Using `outvariable` parameter, I can see `get-childitem` output. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @markfree; my pleasure.